# How to implement the following probability density function using python?

Tags: python, probability-density

How to implement the following probability density function using python?

[image: probability-density]

I tried using the `random.uniform` function in python, but the integral value of the two piecewise uniform distributions is `2`, not `1`! Here is my code:

```py
samples = np.array([random.uniform(-2.5, -2) if random.random() > 0.5
                    else random.uniform(0, 2) for _ in range(1024)])
```

In fact, I am learning about k-Nearest Neighbor Probability Density Estimation, a method for estimating the probability density of unknown sample points from existing sample distributions. Below is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def density_estimation(samples: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    density = np.zeros_like(X)
    n = samples.shape[0]
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        V = np.sort(np.abs(samples - X[i]))[k]
        density[i] = k / (n * V)
    return density


# samples = np.array([random.uniform(-2.5, -2) if random.random() > 0.5
#                     else random.uniform(0, 2) for _ in range(1024)])
samples = np.array([random.uniform(-2.5, -2) if random.random() > 0.5
                    else random.uniform(0, 2) for _ in range(102400)])
X = np.linspace(-4, 4, 1000)
k = int(math.sqrt(samples.shape[0]))
density = density_estimation(samples, X, k)
plt.plot(X, density)
plt.show()
```

The probability density function is as follows:

[image]

As you can see from the results, the total integral value is 2, not 1.

Comment: So when you say you want to implement the probability density function, do you mean that you want to be able to draw samples from it? Or, do you just want the functional form of it?

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. According to the probability density expression above, half of the probability produces a uniform distribution of -2.5 to -2, and the other half of the probability produces a uniform distribution of 0 to 2.

Comment: I want to be able to draw samples from it

Comment: Given `samples`, how are you calculating "the integral value of the two piecewise uniform distributions"?

Comment: What you already have looks like it will already correctly draw samples from that distribution.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself clearly, I re-edited the question.

Comment: Your `samples` looks fine - the problem seems to be in the density estimation. Looking at this guide - http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18W_425/Lec7_knn_basis.pdf - it seems like the formula with d=1 should be `(k/n) * (1 / 2Rk(x))`. So in terms of the variables in your function, it looks like you should have `density[i] = k / (n * 2 * V)`